# MSChart multiple real time data series with different data start time

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-4.0, mschart

I am using MS Chart and i display 3 series(spline & stepline) in the same chart area. The data in the chart is real time, Each series get new data points couple of times per second.

Series No.3 starting getting data first, before Series 2 & 1, And i wish that when series 2 & 1 will start getting data(10 second delay~ from series 3), There first element/point will shown in the same vertical line on the chart area where the last element/point of series 3 is, And not from the begining of the chart area(left side, X = 0), as the default.

So if series No.3 having 100 points allready and now series 2 & 1 starting, they start from same "X place" (on the chat area axis) where the 100th element/point of series 3 is.

Here's an image that demonstrates the default status and what i willing to do:

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Each Datapoint must have an X Value and Y Value. You need to write some logic to change the X value of First Datapoint of Series 1&2 to same as last XValue of Series 3. Is there any reason you cannot do that ?

Comment: I tried that, in my case the X Value is string, and its steel dosn't work.